# Using a '||' logical OR operator for comparing strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a simple conditional statement, in which I'm getting a string input from the user, checking if it's equal to something but the nature of my code makes me add a single more operand to operate between

I tried this but it gives an error that you can't operate between two strings, obv there is some logical fallacy but I want a similar solution to this problem

```
if (Console.ReadLine() == ("s"||"S"))
```

Now I know this works if I make a separate variable and just check with it for both "S" and "s", but I want to do it inline and within that single statement, If I add another "Readline()" it will just take two inputs and won't do what I want it to do.

If there is anyway to make this work within that line, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variable outside the condition, but you *can* do everything else in one line.

You can use `is` to make it slightly more readable (but only works for literal comparison).

```
string input;
if ((input = Console.ReadLine()) is "s" or "S")
```

Or if you have to use `==` then

```
string input;
if ((input = Console.ReadLine()) == "s" || input == "S")
```

Would I suggest doing this? No. Do the sane thing by not cramming all this logic in one line.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input is "s" or "S")
```

Comment: the first solution "is " operator does just what I want perfectly thanks, but I am willing to learn more string comparisons in other answers too

Answer (score -2):

What about trying

```
if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "s")
```

Comment: This solution falls apart as soon as the options are not the same letter with different capitalization.

Comment: And `string.Equals` with the appropriate comparer would be better than this solution.

Comment: Using `.ToLower()` creates a new `String` instance (and associated memory copy) which adds to the GC heap which is inefficient. Instead of normalizing strings for case-insensitive comparison use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead - which will be zero-allocation. (Also, using `ToLower()` is incorrect anyway because it's sensitive to `CurrentCulture` _and_ [it doesn't normalize certain non-Latin characters correctly, such as the Turkish "I"](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/) - use `.ToUpperInvariant()` instead.